# Assessing Whether the Series $\sum_\limits{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n} = 1 - x^2 + x^4 - x^6 + \dots$ Converges (conditional/absolute) or Diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

It's been a while since I've used the various tests for convergence (conditional/absolute) and divergence, and I can't remember which test needs to be used and how to assess whether the series $\sum_\limits{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n} = 1 - x^2 + x^4 - x^6 + \dots$ converges (conditionally/absolutely) or diverges?

I would appreciate it if people could please explain the test that I need to use, why this test needs to be used (within this context), and how it is used (within this context).

Addition:

From *Thomas's Calculus*, 14th Edition:

[image]

Comment: Hint: $x^2\ge 0$ for all $x$, therefore the series is alternating. For absolute convergence, we could see that series built by the absolute values is the geometric series on $x^2$.

Comment: You do not need to use a test. This is a geometric series with ratio $-x^2$ so you can just use $|-x^2|<1$

Comment: @B.Martin Ahh, thanks. What theorem is this? I need to read up on it, since I haven’t dealt with convergence/divergence for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_\limits{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n} = 1 - x^2 + x^4 - x^6 + \dots$$

is a geometric series which converges to $$\frac {1}{1+x^2}$$ for $|x|<1$ and diverges otherwise.